# Difference in type checking an object variable and an object literal as a function parameter in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

**CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-tree-i8uem?file=/src/index.ts

I have a function that takes an object param of a certain type.

```
interface MY_INTERFACE {
  PROP_A: string;                  // IN MY REAL CASE, THESE ARE NOT STRINGS
  PROP_B: string;
  PROP_C: string;
  PROP_D: string;
}

type OBJECT_PARAM_TYPE = {
  [key in keyof MY_INTERFACE]: string;
};
```

The object type `OBJECT_PARAM_TYPE` must have all the properties that are present in `MY_INTERFACE` and a string as a value.

The function I'm testing it with:

```
function someFunction(x: OBJECT_PARAM_TYPE): OBJECT_PARAM_TYPE {
  return x;
}
```

I'm getting different results when I'm passing the object as a variable, or an object literal.

**TEST 1**

Passing an object with an extra property `PROP_E`.

[image]

**TEST 1 - Result**

The code `result1` that passses the object as a variable, does not trigger any errors.

Only the code `result2` that passes the object literal is triggering the error for the extra property.

Why is that?

**TEST 2**

Passing an object with a missing property `PROP_D`.

[image]

**TEST 2 - Result**

Both codes show errors for the missing property `PROP_D`, which was the expected behavior for this test.

---

**QUESTION**

Why Typescript will not trigger the error for the extra property when I'm passing the object as a variable in **TEST 1** ?

**CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-tree-i8uem?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852278/why-can-i-avoid-excess-property-check-in-typescript-just-by-passing-a-reference