# Enforce strict check for optional properties in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to make it so that "foo" does not accept "bar" since there is a chance that property "c" is present in "bar" (see example below).

```
type a = {a : number, b: number}; // create mode form values
type b = {a: number, b: number, id: number}; // edit mode form values

type c = {a: number, b: number, c?: number}; // values received from database
const bar: c = {a: 12, b: 10, c: 15};

const foo: a | b = bar; // does not throw compile error
// const foo: a | b = {a: 12, b: 10, c: 15}; // shows error 
// const foo: a | b = {a: 12, b: 10, c: 15} as c; // no error
```

I came across this bug when i wanted to send "foo" to the server but the server does not accept value of {..., c: 15} that was assigned to "foo". What should i do here?

**Edit** - For future readers, this issue has not been solved yet. Here is the link to an ongoing discussion https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936

Comment: @kaya3 it does not answer the question :(. I can assign value of bar to foo directly and get the compiler error, but when i cast the value to type "c" compiler does not throw error.
Eg. const foo: a | b = {a: 12, b: 10, c: 15}; // shows error 
      const foo: a | b = {a: 12, b: 10, c: 15} as c; // no error \n
      const foo: a | b = bar; // no error

Comment: I have udpated the question to give more examples

Comment: Your question asks "what should I do here?", which is answered by the linked duplicate (i.e. what you want is exact types, but TS doesn't have them). If the question you actually want an answer to is "why does it give an error if I assign the object literal directly, but no error when I assign it via a variable?" then it's a duplicate of this one: [Why can I avoid excess property check in typescript just by passing a reference to an object to a function rather than the object in its literal form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52852278/12299000)

Comment: @kaya3 thanks, it appears typescript yet lacks the feature. How do you suggest i can go about this, if there is any way at all to enforce type safety? This appears to break apps silently on production.

Comment: I would suggest that the ideal solution is to fix the bug in the server, so that it does not fail when the extra property is provided. Otherwise you could do something like `const requestData = {a: foo.a, b: foo.b};` in the function that sends the request to the server.