Generic object parameter does not match type in Typescript
I've defined 2 objects using a generic type alias, one with keys A, B and the other with A, B, C, D. Type2 contains Type1.
// Define type aliases where Type1 { A, B } and Type2 { A, B, C, D }
type Type1 = 'A' | 'B';
type Type2 = Type1 | 'C' | 'D';

// Define a simple dictionary with string keys and values
type Dict<T extends string> = { [index in T]: string };

// Define dictionaries for Type1 and Type2
const dict1: Dict<Type1> = { A: 'a', B: 'b' },
    dict2: Dict<Type2> = { A: 'a', B: 'b', C: 'c', D: 'd' };

Here's a function that takes in a string from one of those type aliases and returns the object value:
// This function takes in a key and dictionary of the same type and logs the value
function func<T extends string>(key: T, dict: Dict<T>): void {
    console.log(dict[key]);
}

The idea is that func<Type1>(...) should only accept dict1 in its second parameter. This example usage makes perfect sense:
func<Type1>('A', dict1);
func<Type2>('A', dict2);
func('A', dict1);
func('A', dict2);

However things start to get muddy here. I clearly ask for a Dict<Type1> but it's okay with a Dict<Type2>. It sort of makes sense because Dict<Type2> contains a Dict<Type1>.
// No error here?!
func<Type1>('A', dict2);

So here's the exact same code, with dict2 spelled out:
// Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'C' does not exist in type 'Dict<Type1>'. ts(2353)
func<Type1>('A', { A: 'a', B: 'b', C: 'c', D: 'd' });

This is what I wanted to see to begin with. Why is the last example okay but this one throws an error? How can I make both of these throw an error?
TS Playground

Typescript does not have "exact" types and excess properties are usually allowed, except in object literals where the compiler has decided it's probably a mistake. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852278/why-can-i-avoid-excess-property-check-in-typescript-just-by-passing-a-reference. With some effort, you can implement exact types, though I'd typically advise against it. Do those answers answer your question?

index is an unconventional name for a type parameter; it's a generic type parameter and you should use a name that indicates this, like K or possibly Index.
