Unexpected Behavior with Instance Type - Accepting additional properties not defined on the type
I am encountering unexpected behavior with the InstanceType Utility Type. I want to define a function which accepts a class constructor and an instance of that class.
For example:
export type Class<T=any> = { new(...args: any[]): T; };

function acceptClassAndInstance<T extends Class>(model: T, instance: InstanceType<T>) {
  
}

The problem that I am running into is that the function will accept any object as long as it contains the properties as defined on the type, but the issue is that it also accepts objects which have additional properties not defined on the type. Here is the complete example:
export type Class<T=any> = { new(...args: any[]): T; };

class AModel {
  foo: string;

  constructor(params: Partial<Pick<AModel, keyof AModel>>) {
    Object.assign(this, params)
  }
}

class BModel {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;

  constructor(params: Partial<Pick<BModel, keyof BModel>>) {
    Object.assign(this, params)
  }
}

function acceptClassAndInstance<T extends Class>(model: T, instance: InstanceType<T>) {
  
}

/* this and only this should work */
const instance = new AModel({ foo: "bar" })
acceptClassAndInstance(AModel, instance)

/* this should fail, but doesn't */
const instance2 = new BModel({ foo: "bar", bar: "baz"})
acceptClassAndInstance(AModel, instance2)

/* and this should fail, but doesn't */
const notAnInstance = { "foo": "bizz", "bar": "barrrrr", "anotherProperty": "should fail" }
acceptClassAndInstance(AModel, notAnInstance)

/* this fails as expected */
const notAnInstance2 = { "bar": "barrrrr", "anotherProperty": "should fail" }
acceptClassAndInstance(AModel, notAnInstance2)

What gives? Is this a bug in typescript? Is there something else I can do to get the expected behavior?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-bkqfyq?file=src%2Fmain.ts,tsconfig.json&terminal=dev

Not a bug. It's a feature. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852278/why-can-i-avoid-excess-property-check-in-typescript-just-by-passing-a-reference and https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#excess-property-checks. Typescript is structural, not nominal. That means that if a type has the required structure of another type, they can be treated as identical. So what problem is this causing you?

This is because excess properties are fine in typescript since the type system is structural. If it quacks like a duck, then it's safe assume it's a duck.
In this case, you can enforce that only instances created by the class constructor are accepted by having having any private field in that class. That means it's impossible for a different type to implement that private, since it's private to only that class.
class A {
    foo: string
}
const a: A = { foo: 'foo' } // fine


class B {
    foo: string
    private bar: string
}
const b: B = { foo: 'foo' } // error


In your case adding that private field to AModel seems to raise the type errors you want.
class AModel {
  foo: string;

  private anything = 'A'

  constructor(params: Partial<Pick<AModel, keyof AModel>>) {
    Object.assign(this, params)
  }
}

See Playground

Just note, you probably don't need to do this. Don't do this on purpose unless you have a good reason and the default type checking is actually causing you a problem.
